# Capturing screen after setting Window to hidden in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to capture the screen after I set the Window Variable to hidden and trigger onPropertyChanged(). Why I also record my own programm?

```
_VisibilityWindow = false;
OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityWindow");


Screenshot.captureAll();

_VisibilityWindow = true;
OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityWindow");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI did not have the chance to update after the property changed.
You can wait until the application finished rendering using the `Dispatcher` instead:

```
_VisibilityWindow = false;
OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityWindow");

System.Windows.Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(() =>
  {
    Screenshot.captureAll();

    _VisibilityWindow = true;
    OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityWindow");
  }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!